# How to loop through Hive Query and use loop variable

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hue

Say I have two tables

```
External table - etable

Internal table - itable
```

and my etable is partitioned based on date.

Now to populate my itable everyday from etable's data I have workflow and coordinator in hue with Hive Query as shown below:

```
ALTER TABLE etable ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (date = '${date}') LOCATION 'path/date=${date}';

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE itable partition(date = '${date}') SELECT * FROM etable WHERE date = '${date}';
```

Now suppose everyday I want to update my data for past `n` days, how do I do that?

E.g.

Lets take `n = 2` and if coordinator is scheduled to run today i.e. `2018-01-20`(yyyy-MM-dd) then it should update data for past `2` days. So the query should update the data for `2018-01-20` and `2018-01-19`. So basically I need to run the above query twice with different date.

Is there any way to loop this query `n` times and use the loop variable, because then I can use `date_sub()` to get different date in each iteration of loop. Or is there any better way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do `

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE itable partition(`date`) 
SELECT * FROM etable
WHERE `date` BETWEEN datesub('${date}', ${n}) AND '${date}'
```

---

Anyways, Hive has no loops. Hue and Oozie won't be able to do that either since you're trying to dynamically build queries

The way you would do this would require a bash loop with `beeline -u jdbc:hive2://server:10000 --hivevar date="value" -f script.sql`

Or you can use Python, Java, or whatever you're comfortable with with to write a loop as long as it can communicate with Hive.

Then, you can schedule that script/code with Oozie